# Rails & Postgres - How do require an either field 1 and field 2 or field 2 and field 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation

I am writing an application for work that begins with user input in a form. I am having difficulty figuring out how to have the model validate either field 1 & field 2 to be valid, or field 2 & field 3. Is that beyond the scope of what a RoRs/Postgres model is supposed to do?

e.g. Either first_name & last_name are required or last_name & birth_date are required.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following using [a custom Active Record validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :conditional_name_validation
  # ...    
  private
    def conditional_name_validation
      unless (first_name && last_name) ||
             (last_name && birth_date)
        error = "You must provide either 'first_name' and 'last_name' or 'last_name' and 'birth_date'"
        errors.add(:base, error)
      end
    end
end
```